# Проблема с маршрутизацией из локальной сети в локальную сеть через глобальную сеть

Tags: iptables

Имею шлюзовый сервер, на нем shell скрипт с такими правилами iptables:

```
#!/bin/sh

IPT="iptables"

# Внешний и внутрений интерфейс
WAN=eth0
LAN=lxcbr0

# Диапазон IP адресов локальной сети
LAN_IP_RANGE=10.0.0.0/24

# Очистка цепочек
$IPT -F
$IPT -F -t nat
$IPT -F -t mangle
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -X

# Запрет всего, что не разрешено
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP

# Разрешение loopback
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Разрешение LAN трафика
$IPT -A INPUT -i $LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o $LAN -j ACCEPT

# Разрешаение трафика в WAN
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o $WAN -j ACCEPT

# Рзрешение части ICMP трафика
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# Разрешение установленных соединений
$IPT -A INPUT -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Отброс неопознаных пакетов
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Отбрас фрагментированных пакетов
#$IPT -A INPUT -f -j DROP
#$IPT -A FORWARD -f -j DROP

# Отброс XMAS пакетов
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Отбрас нулевых пакетов
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Запрет инициализации TCP соединения пакетами без SYN флага
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Разрешение SSH трафика с ограничениями
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --name ssh --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 5 -j DROP
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --name ssh --set -j ACCEPT

# Разрешение NTP трафика из WAN
$IPT -A INPUT -i $WAN -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Направление HTTP трафика на сервер в LAN
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.3:80

...

# Включаем логирование
$IPT -N block_in
$IPT -N block_out
$IPT -N block_fw

$IPT -A INPUT -j block_in
$IPT -A OUTPUT -j block_out
$IPT -A FORWARD -j block_fw

$IPT -A block_in -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix "[IN-BLOCK]"
$IPT -A block_in -j DROP
$IPT -A block_out -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix "[OUT-BLOCK]"
$IPT -A block_out -j DROP
$IPT -A block_fw -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix "[FW-BLOCK]"
$IPT -A block_fw -j DROP

# Сохранние правил
iptables-save  > /etc/iptables_rules
```

Так же происходит включение NAT, но не в данном скрипте.
На сервере 10.0.0.3 есть веб сервер, если я делаю с домашнего ПК `$ curl ip-адрес-шлюзового-сервера` я получаю содержимое страници, если я делаю `$ curl 10.0.0.3` с сервера 10.0.0.3 — получаю содержимое страници, а вот если я делаю с сервера 10.0.0.3 `$ curl WAN-адрес-шлюзового-сервера` я получаю "Connection refused", хотя есть правило, которое перенаправляет http трафик на сервер 10.0.0.3
Подскажите, как правильно разрешить вот такой вот трафик с локалки в локалку через внешний ip, для всех протоколов?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то сервер имеет внешний адрес посредством проброса портов например. И Вы хотите получит к нему доступ по внешнему адресу из тоже локалки, в которой он сам? Так это задача непростая и вряд ли стоит тратить на неё силы. Правило перенаправляет трафик из внешней сети. Как заставить шлюз думать, что локальный трафик тоже внешний - большая загадка. Может маршрутизация по источнику?

Comment: Да, именно. Заморочится мне таки нужно. Возможно, было б неплохо если вы привели пример, а то я не доконца уверен что понял как правильно это сделать

Comment: Извини, примера не будет. Такая задача конечно интересна, но сложная, и смыла доводить её решение до конца в моей практике не было. Вместо этого можно настроить dns-сервер, чтобы в локальной сети www.server.com работал по локальному адресу, в глобальной соответственно по глобальному. И обращаться не по ип, а по имени dns, которое будет всегда одинаковым. Ещё попробовать  вынести сервер в так называемую dmz. Может так будет легче придумать что-нибудь. Или кто другой скажет.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. думал это одним правилом iptables можно сделать. Вариант с DNS мне вполне подходит.